# Best practice to add rows from table to table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a open house api feed that feeds my database hourly. Open house database contains: MLS #, Listing Agent, Listing Office, address, open house date, next open house date.

I want to create a new table that will keep all the records for open house date and next open house date. I can have duplicate MLS #s but need to have different open house dates.

Open house table: Current Week

```
--------------------------------------
MLS    | Open Date | Next Open Date 
12433  | 6/24/15   | 6/25/15           
23223  | 6/22/15   | 6/23/15         
35325  | 6/23/15   | 7/01/15       
--------------------------------------
```

Open house table: Last week

```
--------------------------------------
MLS    | Open Date | Next Open Date 
12433  | 6/15/15   |   n/a     
23223  | 6/18/15   | 6/20/15         
35325  | 6/07/15   |   n/a   
--------------------------------------
```

All Open House History table:

```
--------------------------------------
MLS    | Open Date | Next Open Date 
12433  | 6/24/15   | 6/25/15           
23223  | 6/22/15   | 6/23/15         
35325  | 6/23/15   | 7/01/15 
12433  | 6/15/15   |   n/a     
23223  | 6/18/15   | 6/20/15         
35325  | 6/07/15   |   n/a         
--------------------------------------
```

History table can have same mls #'s but can't have the same open date and next open date.

I tried:

```
INSERT INTO open_house_history (mls_id, open_date, next_open_date)
SELECT mls_id, open_date, next_open_date
FROM open_house
WHERE open_date NOT IN (SELECT open_date FROM open_house_history) 
AND mls_id IN (SELECT mls_id FROM open_house_history)
```

Please help!
Thankyou

Comment: What have you tried so far? Or are you asking us to write the code? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem with the SQL you tried? Is it erroring out? Are you getting the wrong results?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work properly. @Mureinik

Comment: I posted the sql query which doesn't really seem to work with what I want. @tvgemert

Comment: Does it insert anything? Or does it just throw an error?

Comment: It does insert records, but I just want to know if Im doing this right? If not, I want someone pointing me the right direction. Thanks @tvgemert

Answer (score 0):

Your query has an issue because you are excluding all records where the Open Date is already in your table.

```
WHERE open_date NOT IN (SELECT open_date FROM open_house_history)
```

If you were to get a different listing with the same date, it would be excluded. A listing with the same ID but a different date would also be excluded.

In instances like this, I combine all the fields into one string and use that for the comparison:

```
INSERT INTO open_house_history (mls_id, open_date, next_open_date)
SELECT mls_id, open_date, next_open_date
FROM open_house
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), open_date, 112) + '|' + mls_id NOT IN (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), open_date, 112) + '|' + mls_id FROM open_house_history)
```

Comment: Why would I convert it to varchar? its a datetime field

Comment: You convert the date so you can combine it and MLS ID in one text field so you can check if that previous combination has previously been added. If you check for one or the other, you'll ignore other MLS IDs with the same date and the same MLS ID with a different date.

Comment: Is there a simpler way to this. Seems like were create a extra column.

Comment: You could instead do a **LEFT JOIN** your History table on the **MSL ID** and **Date** and insert the ones where MLS_ID of your history table is NULL but that would be a bit more work (though you wouldn't have to combine the two fields for the WHERE clause).